# Retrieve list of records for a week in postgres SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

Data::::::

```
21,600,false,203,203,666,'2017-11-23 13:10:56+05:30'

20,600,false,203,203,666,'2017-11-22 13:10:56+05:30'

19,600,false,203,203,666,'2017-11-21 13:10:56+05:30'

18,600,false,203,203,666,'2017-11-20 13:12:56+05:30'

17,120,false,203,203,666,'2017-11-20 13:10:56+05:30'
```

---

```
select * 
from progress_Report 
where programid = 666 and datedone>='2017-11-19 00:00:00.000000 +05:30:00'  
and datedone<='2017-11-27 00:00:00.000000 +05:30:00' 
order by datedone desc
```

This is my query if you check the data, For date 2017-11-20 I need latest updated value but I am getting all inserted records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `ROW_NUMBER` with a partition on the date:

```
SELECT col1, col2, ...
FROM
(
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY datedone::date ORDER BY datedone DESC) rn
    FROM progress_Report
    WHERE programid = 666
) t
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Your current output is expected given that the date range in your query includes all the records, at least the ones which you showed in the question.